# Thread for show pics while a function is running

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, binding

I have a function, which takes a long time.

When the function is running, I would like to show some pictures, but this code doesn't work. Why ?

(**I must use only framework 4**)

This is the code XAML

```
<Image Width="33" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding ImagePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

This is the code

```
public bool Cmd_TestExe()
 {
Thread trd_A = new Thread(MyThreadTask_ShowImg);
Thread_Status = false;
trd_A.Start();

if (My_Slow_Function(sCon) == false) {
    displayMessage(Status_Failure);}
 }





public void Wait(int sleep) 
{
dynamic dFrame = new DispatcherFrame();

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(sleep);
    dFrame.Continue = false;
});
Dispatcher.PushFrame(dFrame);
 }





public void MyThreadTask_ShowImg()
 {
while (Thread_Status == false) {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (Second(Now) % (2) == 0) {
            ImagePath = "/Images/exit.png";
            Wait(250);
        } else {
            ImagePath = "/Images/excel.png";
            Wait(250);
            Console.WriteLine(Now);
        }
    }));
}
 }
```

...and this is the property

```
private string _ImagePath { get; set; }
public string ImagePath {
get { return _ImagePath; }
set {
    _ImagePath = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
}
 }
```

Comment: Don't try to manage threads yourself, you'll usually mess it up with the frameworks thread pool. Recommended way to do async or background operations is to use the TPL (Task Parallel Library) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx as it will significantly smplify the code and allow the TPL to optimally manage the threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to return a bool in your Cmd_TestExe Method.

Second, I've never use DispatcherFrame, but this is how I would do :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Thread myLittleThread;
    bool stop;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        set
        {
            myLittleImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value));
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitThread();
    }

    private void InitThread()
    {
        myLittleThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        stop = false;
        Application.Current.Exit += MyLittleApplication_Exit;
        myLittleThread.Start();
    }


    private void MyLittleApplication_Exit(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        stop = true;
    }

    private void DoWork(){
        string newImageSource;
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0)
            {
                newImageSource = "SomeRandomFooImage.png";
            }
            else
            {
                newImageSource = "MyLittleRandomImage.png";
            }

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ImageSource = newImageSource;
            }));

            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }

}
```

and XAML :

```
<Image Name="myLittleImage" ></Image>
```